# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BuiltinFunctionType' in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

i write a code in python language which uses copy module. when i run this code in `pycharm` console it has no error but in pycharm GUI environment it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "C:/....../python/deepshallowcopy.py", line 2, in <module> 
        from copy mport deepcopy 
    File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 114, in <module>
        types.BuiltinFunctionType, type(Ellipsis),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BuiltinFunctionType'
```

My code is:

```
from copy import deepcopy
col3=["rrrr","bbbb"]
col4=deepcopy(col3)
print(col3,col4)
col3[0]="jfjdhf"
print(col3,col4)
```

Comment: Is there more traceback than just the AttributeError?

Comment: sorry ,col2 is a typo

Comment: this is complete erorr line: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/....../python/deepshallowcopy.py", line 2, in <module>
    from copy import deepcopy
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 114, in <module>
    types.BuiltinFunctionType, type(Ellipsis),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BuiltinFunctionType'
'

Comment: Don't use a comment to add tracebacks/code (since it lacks formatting); instead, just [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29875034/edit) your question and add the traceback.

Answer (score 8):

Taking a closer look at your traceback,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/....../python/deepshallowcopy.py", line 2, in <module>
    from copy import deepcopy
  File "C:\Python34\lib\copy.py", line 114, in <module>
    types.BuiltinFunctionType, type(Ellipsis),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BuiltinFunctionType'
```

you must have a Python file named `types.py` in the same folder that you are running your `deepshallowcopy.py` file.

I was able to reproduce this error by running your script in the same folder as a file named `types.py`.